# JavaScript transition with the display property?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I make a certain element fade in when I hover over another one, and make it fade out when my mouse isn't on the element anymore?

I tried adding a `transition` in the CSS, but that doesn't seem to work (which I already predicted, because it's in fact the JavaScript that makes the div visible using DOM...).

I got the fiddle over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YSbakker/L4Hzw/19/)

Comment: If your div's are adjacent or inside each other.. why would you need javascript?

Comment: Do you want the text below the `div` covered up when the `div` fades in or not?

Comment: @soktinpk Not necessarily, I just needed to know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I thought about soktinpk's solution. Opacity can be animated with css so it's the best bet.

However, it takes up the space even when it is not shown. To prevent that, you could make it `position:absolute`. But even then, elements behind it will not be clickable.

#### Here is a more robust solution with a combination of @soktinpk's ideas

To prevent that, hide it with <strike>`display:none`</strike> when it is not visible.

### Edit

Actually, `visibility:hidden` seems to work better when fading back in.

**HTML**

```
<div id="button" onmouseover="showMenu()" onmouseout="hideMenu()">
    <!-- placing it inside will allow it to be positioned as wanted -->
    <div id="menu"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#button {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,100);
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    position:relative; // All absolutely positioned elements inside are relative to this element
}

#menu {
    background-color: rgb(0,100,0);
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    position:absolute; // So that it displays at the right position
    top:100%;
    left:0;
}
```

**JS**

```
var time_out;
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

function showMenu() {
    clearTimeout(time_out);
    menu.style.visibility = "visible";
    menu.style.opacity = 1;
}

function hideMenu() {
    clearTimeout(time_out);
    menu.style.opacity = 0;
    // This will hide it when the animation is over
    time_out = setTimeout(function(){menu.style.visibility = "hidden";},1000);
}
```

## JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: Hmm, thanks, this seems like the best solution to me. Thanks everyone else for the effort!

Comment: One more question, why exactly do you need to set the `top` to `100%` in the css file under `#menu`?

Comment: @YSbakker `top:100%` makes the menu appear under the button (100% of the button's height, from its top). Play with this value, try `top:50%` or `bottom:0` and you'll see what I mean. Also I forgot to add `margin-left:-9999px` to the menu so that it works the first time. I'm adding this to the answer.

Comment: This solution is "hacky", using the margin. You should use `display: none;`

Comment: @blex Actually, never mind. For some reason, when using `display: none`, the animation is choppy when fading in (if it's completely faded out, tested in chrome). I updated my answer with how I did it (`visibility: none, position: absolute`). But my answer keeps the text below it always showing (it's not covered up). That could be a good thing or a bad thing, depending on what you want.

Comment: @soktinpk True. In my jsFiddle, the problem seems fixed when using visibility:hidden. But good job for binding the `transitionend` in your answer instead of setting a fixed timeout.

Comment: @blex okay, I get it, but would the menu be scrollable? I mean that if I would have a fixed header, and then when I would scroll, would the menu stay in the same spot or would it stay visible on the screen?

Comment: @YSbakker it would be fixed too: http://jsfiddle.net/L4Hzw/28/ but that's a whole other question

Answer (score 2):

Here is a mostly css answer: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7GuR/4/

Instead of using `display` since that has only two modes (in this case: `none` and `block`) you should use `opacity`. That will give you a smooth transition.

Css:

```
#menu {
    background-color: rgb(0,100,0);
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    // Notice
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function showMenu() {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.opacity = 1;
}

function hideMenu() {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.opacity = 0;
    // If you want, you can bind an "end" event to css transition and
    // set "display" to none when that happens
}
```

As some have pointed out, the element will still take up space even after its opacity is set to `0`. To prevent this, you can set `display` to `none` after the animation has ended, as I said in the example (sorry if this wasn't clear). This is much better than changing the `margin`, which is a "hacky" solution.

**Edit**: Okay, the `display: none`, works, but for some reason, with `display: block`, the animation is choppy when you fade back in, if it's completely faded out previously (in chrome, at least). So, instead of `display: none`, I used a combination of `position: absolute`, and `visibility: hidden`, to hide the element:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7GuR/4/

```
var menu = document.getElementById("menu"), button = document.getElementById("button");

function showMenu() {
    menu.style.opacity = 1;
    // Reset visibility and position
    menu.style.visibility = "visible";
    menu.style.position = "static";
    menu.removeEventListener("transitionend", setDisplayNone, false);
}

function hideMenu() {
    menu.style.opacity = 0;
    // I prefer using transitionend to setTimeout
    // transitionend is more extendable, and it makes more sense to me
    menu.addEventListener("transitionend", setDisplayNone, false);
}

function setDisplayNone() {
    menu.style.visibility = "hidden";
    menu.style.position = "absolute";
}

button.addEventListener("mouseover", showMenu);
button.addEventListener("mouseout", hideMenu);
```

The only major difference between my answer and the accepted answer is that the text will always be visible (the fading element won't cover it).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure css solution for your specific html:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Hzw/23/)

### html

```
<div id="button" onmouseover="showMenu()" onmouseout="hideMenu()"></div>
<div id="menu"></div>
```

for the css I used opacity instead of display and added the following:

### css

```
#button:hover ~ #menu,
#menu:hover {
    opacity:1;
    height:100px;
}
```